# How to track changes in the board of directors within the same firm

Tags: loops, stata

In Stata I need to create a new variable "changes in the board of directors" which indicates whether the same directors are observed in the same firm over time. Consider an example below:

```
clear
input dirid firmid year
1 10 2006
2 10 2006
3 10 2006
1 10 2007
2 10 2007
3 10 2007
1 10 2008
2 10 2008
3 10 2008
4 10 2008
3 10 2009
4 10 2009
end
```

Directors ID 1, 2, and 3 are in firm 10 in 2006 and in 2007. So there was no change in the board of directors from t-1 to t. The variable "changes in the board of directors" should be 0. However, in 2008 a new director came to the board dirid = 4, so there was a change in the board and the variable should be 1. The same in 2009 because dirid 1 and 2 left the company. So any change, whether the entrance or exit of directors, should be reported with 1 in the new binary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it. I think it should cope with directors leaving and later coming back.

```
clear
input dirid firmid year
1 10 2006
2 10 2006
3 10 2006
1 10 2007
2 10 2007
3 10 2007
1 10 2008
2 10 2008
3 10 2008
4 10 2008
3 10 2009
4 10 2009
end

bysort firmid year (dirid) : gen board = strofreal(dirid) if _n == 1 
by firmid year : replace board = board[_n-1] + " " + strofreal(dirid) if _n > 1 
by firmid year : replace board = board[_N] 

by firmid : gen anychange = year != year[_n-1] & board != board[_n-1] 
bysort firmid year (anychange) : replace anychange = anychange[_N] 

sort firmid year dirid 
list, sepby(firmid year) 


    +--------------------------------------------+
     | dirid   firmid   year     board   anycha~e |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1       10   2006     1 2 3          1 |
  2. |     2       10   2006     1 2 3          1 |
  3. |     3       10   2006     1 2 3          1 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  4. |     1       10   2007     1 2 3          0 |
  5. |     2       10   2007     1 2 3          0 |
  6. |     3       10   2007     1 2 3          0 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  7. |     1       10   2008   1 2 3 4          1 |
  8. |     2       10   2008   1 2 3 4          1 |
  9. |     3       10   2008   1 2 3 4          1 |
 10. |     4       10   2008   1 2 3 4          1 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
 11. |     3       10   2009       3 4          1 |
 12. |     4       10   2009       3 4          1 |
     +--------------------------------------------+


See also [this paper][1] on concatenating rowwise. 


  [1]: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1536867X20909698
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I need and it works very fast even for my big sample of dirid. I just replaced anychange = 0 for the first year when the firm appears in the sample. It works for any change, also if the same dirid leaves and later comes back. Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
clear
input dirid firmid year
1 10 2006
2 10 2006
3 10 2006
1 10 2007
2 10 2007
3 10 2007
1 10 2008
2 10 2008
3 10 2008
4 10 2008
3 10 2009
4 10 2009
end

bysort firmid year (dirid): gen n = _n
reshape wide n, i(firmid year) j(dirid)
egen all_directors = concat(n*)
bysort firmid (year): gen change = all_directors != all_directors[_n-1] & _n > 1
reshape long
drop if missing(n)
drop all_directors n
```

Comment: Concatenation works fine for directors 1 2 3 4, but if you have directors 11 12 13 .... 101 102 103 .... you may need extra punctuation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Yes, it gives me exactly what I want, but I have in reality 3 million observations of directors, so reshape command already took a lot of time to run. It would be helpful if this code can be adjusted to larger samples.